# How to extend parent state controller with onmouseover to child states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, states

I have a simple angularjs controller which uses jquery that logs something to the console when mouse goes over an anchor element:

```
app.controller('MenuController', function() {
    $("a").on('mouseover', function (e) {
        console.log("mouser over a link");
    });
});
```

I am using ui-router for organizing my app states:

```
app.config(["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider", function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect
    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('menu', {
            controller: "MenuController",
            controllerAs: "menuCtrl",
            templateUrl: "partials/menu.html"
        })
            .state('menu.menu', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: "partials/menu.menu.html"
            })
            .state('menu.difficulty', {
                url: '/difficulty',
                templateUrl: "partials/menu.difficulty.html",
                controller: "DifficultyController",
                controllerAs: "difCtrl"
            })
            .state('menu.settings', {
                url: "/settings",
                templateUrl: "partials/menu.settings.html"
            })
}]);
```

My basic html for the menu is in the *menu.html* file:

```
<!-- view - menu -->
<div ui-view>
    <!-- nested views -->
</div>
```

Inside here a bunch of nested views get inserted through states. These views have a lot of anchor elements yet nothing happens when mouse goes over them. Why is that so? Shouldn't parent state controller expand on to child states? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The data which is bound to $scope in parent controller is accessible in the child states because the parent controller always runs if we access the child state.
In Menu Controller,If write write

```
$scope.name = 'XYZ'
```

This $scope.name is accessible in every child controller using $scope.name.

EDIT:
In your MenuController bind this anchor on document like this and It will work

```
app.controller('MenuController', function() {
  $(document).on('mouseover','a', function (e) {
    console.log("mouser over a link");
  });
});
```

Comment: So the problem is jquery and not angular? Can jquery events somehow get inherited?

Comment: The problem is not with angular js. I have edited my answer Please check this